# Blazor injects ServerAuthenticationStateProvider instead of my AuthenticationStateProvider implementation

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I added my `AuthenticationStateProvider` as a Singleton Service and injected the `AuthenticationStateProvider` at the top of my Login Razor-Page. However, when I try to access it in the Login-Page the type of the state provider is `ServerAuthenticationStateProvider` instead of my class.

Answer (score 0):

Most likeley you added your service before calling `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();` which overrides your `AuthenticationStateProvider`. To solve the problem you only have to add your provider **after** ServerSideBlazor.